# Dual hardrive Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

I have a computer with two hardrives. One of them has windows 7 installed on it. The other is blank and formated. I was wondering how I can install ubuntu onto the second hardrive but not the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all of the partitions from the unused drive it should be obvious in the installation which drive to install Ubuntu to. You could also disconnect the drive with windows during the installation and configure the dual boot once Ubuntu is installed.